# Particular local Django deployment. Fabric?

Tags: python, django, bash, setuptools, fabric

I had developed a classic Python Django web application on my local enviroment.
Then, I used Cython to compile some my app's modules as dynamic library (*.so files) to "protect" the source code.
Now, I need to distribute my Django app to one customer (for testing purpose) and I want to provide you all my Django app (with its files) but without some specific files and folders (ex: .git folder, *.pyc, *.py, javascript unobfuscated sources, etc...).

I would like to have some bash command (ex: python setup.py local_deploy) to automatic copy entire app's folder to another folder (ex: build) and remove a specific list of folders or file patterns.

Do you have any suggestion to do that?

Comment: .. sounds to me like you want to generate it, zip it and hand it over to them -- not by ssh means.. so, bash? Or python.. if its as simple as i think, just plain ol' bash.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi, what I need is a build script in which I can add a list of folders to copy and a list of folders and file names to exclude for copy. I need that because I generate the build many time and I do not want to forget some files or folders whenever.

Comment: Right, both would do fine. If you find yourself writing more bash commands than python ones.. then the answer is clear, if not python. But it doesnt sound like you need fabric: other than just wanting to do `fab build` or what-ever other command you think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you package your application for deployment, as you said, by running `python setup.py sdist` or [another setuptools script command](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#command-reference).

You can specify [which package/modules/data to include](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files) and/or [use a `MANIFEST.in` file](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest) to include/exclude files/directories matching specified patterns.

NB if you need to perform additional steps (besides selecting the correct files and packaging them), you may also [add a custom command to `setup.py`](http://blog.ziade.org/2007/09/30/extending-setuptools-adding-a-new-command/). Though personally, I'd use a bash script / fabric to perform those, outside of packaging..